# Where did the wifi sleep policy go in ICS?

Tags: wi-fi, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, standby

With the update to Android 4.0.3, I noticed that the **wifi is always on**.

I used to have the sleep policy where is turns itself of when ilse for some time.

Where did this feature go with ICS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On a pretty much vanilla build on my EVO, I can get to it by going into
`Settings->Wifi->(Menu Button)->Advanced`. It's listed as "Keep WiFi on during sleep". Just be sure to tap on the left half of the "Wifi" menu item, since the right half is simply the toggle.

Comment: Indeed! Thank you! The button on the right was quite confusing. Also, I have a big thumb and whenever I touched the bar, I would simply toggle the wifi on/off.

Comment: As it turns out, the wifi is still on all the time! No matter which option I choose... Reset did not help.

Comment: @Matt: Hm, well that certainly sounds like a bug!

Comment: Holy cow, how long had I been looking for that option!  Many thanks @eldarerathis for the directions, I've now found it and set it.  Nice.